# Is it possible to Union two ranges? - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, union

I m try to `Union` two ranges using `Union` in VBA by i m getting the below error on line `Set rngBothRanges = Union(rngControl, rngFinished)`. Any ideas?

[image]

**Code:**

```
Dim arrHeaders As Variant
Dim rngControl As Range
Dim rngFinished As Range
Dim rngBothRanges As Range

Set rngControl = wsControl.Range("A1")
Set rngFinished = wsFinished.Range("A1:H1")

Set rngBothRanges = Union(rngControl, rngFinished)
```

Comment: You can only Union ranges on the same worksheet

Comment: What are you trying to achieve if I may ask?

Comment: To assign the same formatting to multiple range in different worksheets

Comment: Perfect username. One would have to iterate through each range. If you are trying to do this to a large amount of ranges and the ranges are not entirely simple to distinguish, consider storing them in a `collection`, allowing for iteration at the end in a wrapper function.